# Installing headless chrome without sudo

Tags: sudo, headless

I am using [Dreamhost VPS which doesn't provide `sudo` capability](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216994417-How-to-manage-your-VPS-without-an-admin-user). Dreamhost runs on Ubuntu.

My final goal is to be able to use Ruby to run headless web browser. I picked `Watir` gem and it requires `chromedriver`.

I installed `chromedriver` into my home directory `~/chrome/`, and added it to my $PATH.

I get an error

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in
`assert_ok': unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

[It seems I need to install `Xvfb`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri) and all guides suggest `sudo apt-get install`, which I can't do.

Even if I install Xvfb as standalone, it lacks a lot of extra stuff from X11:

```
[myServer]$ Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24
(WW) Could not open RGB file "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/rgb.txt"; will use built-in copy.
_XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/ps554048:1
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for inet6
error opening security policy file /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/CID/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
```

**Temporary solution** is to get instance on Amazon Web Services which allows 100% sudo and install all the necessary packages

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Debian or Debian-based system and has `apt` installed, you can still use it - sorta.

Get a list of the URLs that `apt-get install ....` would download from - note that if there are packages already downloaded, it won't print the URL since the file exists under `/var/cache/apt/archive`.

```
user@darkstar:~$ apt-get upgrade --allow-unauthenticated -y --print-uris
```

URLs will be at the bottom of the output, you can parse them out with `grep` if needed.  Anyway, gather all of the `.deb` files needed for this, and then on a machine where you do have root use `alien` to convert from `deb` format to `.tgz` (aka `.tar.gz`).  Much like a Slackware package, it will contain a directory tree from the root `/` all the way down to wherever the file(s) actually live.

Once they are all converted, extract them all to some directory.  Go to that directory, and create a new `.tar.gz` file containing the full ball of wax, scp to your webserver, extract, and then edit or set your `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc. as needed.

Comment: it's ubuntu. Thanks! I couldn't find manual on going around `apt-get` myself